# Computing the ratio of unpolarized QED and QCD cross section

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

How is the last equality of the equation

$$
\frac{\sigma_{QCD}}{\sigma_{QED}}=\frac{1}{3*3}(tr T^a T^b)^2=\frac{2}{9}
$$

derived, where $T^{a,b}$ are the basis matrices of SU(3)?

Comment: Um...it is given because it is true? Do you want to know how to *derive* it?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see how the last equality is derived.

Comment: I just edited the question.